# Unresponsive to collisions when using path transitions

Tags: java, javafx

My intent is to create a game where a ball is shot at a target. However, I'd prefer a general answer to this question.

```
Circle ball = new Circle(x1,y1,r);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x2,y2,w,h);
Line path = new Line(x1,y1,x3,y3);

PathTransition pathTrans = new PathTransition(Duration.millis(t), path, ball);
pathTrans.play();

if (ball.getBoundsInParent().intersects(rect.getBoundsInParent())) 
{
  //foo
}
```

Why doesn't the program catch the collision?

If any clarification is desired, I'll be happy to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing for the collision immediately after starting the animation. Unless the two intersect at the beginning of the animation, it will test false.

You need to repeat the test any time one of the objects moves. Probably the best way is to create a `BooleanBinding` that is bound to both `boundsInParent` properties, and listen for changes in its value:

```
BooleanBinding collision = Bindings.createBooleanBinding( () -> 
    ball.getBoundsInParent().intersects(rect.getBoundsInParent()),
    ball.boundsInParentProperty(),
    rect.boundsInParentProperty());

collision.addListener((obs, wasColliding, isNowColliding) -> {
    if (isNowColliding) {
        // foo
    }
});
```

(A more naïve approach would just be to add a listener to `ball.boundsInParentProperty()` and a listener to `rect.boundsInParentProperty()`, and to test for collision in each listener. That duplicates code, though, and I think it would be less efficient.)

Comment: Incidentally, the bounds of the shapes are going to be the smallest rectangle completely containing the shape. So if the circle hits the rectangle on the corner, you'll still see a small gap between the visible parts of the two shapes. You may need to do a considerable amount of geometry to get really good collision detection working.